# How do I show a 403 error page when the server returns a 403 error code?

Tags: 8

I use the nginx config file from https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/recipes/drupal/

It has return 403 and deny all on some file.
Ex. When I visit `/core/CHANGELOG.txt`, nginx returns default 403 Forbidden page.
I want it to display **drupal 403 error page** not nginx white default 403 page.

I have tried adding `error_page 403 /403`  but it returns

> ## Not Found
>
> The requested URL "http://mysite/core/CHANGELOG.txt" was not found on this server.

Comment: location ~ ^/core/.*\.txt$ {
        return 403;
    } Add this in your conf file. I hope this should work.

Comment: @sarathkm From my config file, I already have deny all on all .txt file so it return nginx default 403 page but what I want is to return **Drupal 403 page** that I set in `/admin/config/system/site-information`.

Comment: Then you need to let Drupal handle the errors instead of nginx as you have configured nginx to do so.

Comment: @mradcliffe Is there any module to use or I have to write it.

Comment: Quoting yourself "I already have deny all on all .txt file so it return nginx default 403 page". So undo that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From @googletorp and my google I found this solution

I added `error_page 418 = @blablabla; return 418;`.

```
location ~* \.(txt|log)$ {
    allow 192.168.0.0/16;
    deny all;
    error_page 418 = @blablabla; return 418;
}

location @blablabla {
    rewrite ^ /blablabla break;

    proxy_pass       http://localhost;
    proxy_set_header Host      $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
}
```

This will return to 404 page as `/blablabla` is not found.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is to configure nginx to serve a drupal page that generates a 403 page. There are severals ways to do this.

The easy solution is to route the traffic to Drupal (the index.php file), which would generate a 404 since the page doesn't exist in Drupal.

I think doing

```
location ~* \.(txt|log)$ {
  try_files @rewrite
}
```

should accomplish this for `.txt` and `.log` files. It should try to serve the file from Drupal. By default this will be a 404, but you can add the a route for specific files and return 403 instead.